# Binomial Probability Distribution and Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: probability

How many times do we have to flip a balanced coin to be able to assert with a probability of at most .01 that the difference between the proportion of tails and .50 will be atleast .04 ?

My attempt : I inferred form the following question that the proportion of tails must lie between .46 and .54 . Then I went on to use chebyshev's theorem to find the value of k . Which comes out to be 10. Now that I had done with this, I had to solve the inequality 
$n*\frac{1}{2} + n^{-1/2}*(1/4) < \frac{54}{100}*n $

Which is giving me an answer in fractions . But obviously n can't be in fractions.

Please tell me the correct method to solve the question , and also point the flaw in mine.

Comment: You mean "at most $.04$?  No problem getting fractions...just choose the nearest integer which still satisfies the inequality. Chebysheff is a coarse tool to use here...it applies to a very broad class of distributions (finite mean and variance) but here you know a lot about the distribution.  $n$ will certainly be large so you can use the normal approximation, (mean $\frac n2$, st.dev. $\sqrt {np(1-p)}=\sqrt {\frac n4}$.)

Comment: Yes I could have used the normal distribution too , it is expected that the question is to be solved without the help of any external tables . Hence I stuck to chebyshev.
No as far the probability goes the question explicitly states  atleast .04 @lulu

Comment: Yes, I misread.  "at least $.04$" makes sense.  But I don't understand the numbers you are getting.  If I use the normal approximation, and $n=50000$ then I see that the probability that the proportion of tails lies in $[.46,.54]$ is $.9831$.  so $50000$ is too small (at least as I am reading the problem).  Your numbers are coming out in the low single digits.  But there's no sensible way I could use my method without a table or computer so perhaps I am solving a different problem.

Comment: Apologies...my numbers we're off (just waking up here).  Still, though, I am seeing about $n=880$.  Let's approximate that:  at $n=880$ I'd get $\sigma \sim 14.75$.  Now. $.54*880\sim 475$ so we are talking about $2.4\sigma$.  Sounds about right.

Comment: The $k\sigma $ = ${n^{ - \frac{1}{2}}} \times (\frac{1}{4})$ appears to be incorrect. See my exposition below.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava If you find the answer I gave useful can you accept this and close the question. This is customary on the website. Also it has taken time to answer - as have the comments that have been made concerning your interesting question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is ${\rm B}(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{4})$ and Chebyshev states $$P(|X - \mu | \ge k\sigma ) \le \frac{1}{{{k^2}}}$$
Then $\mu  = .5n$, $\sigma  = \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{{{k^2}}} = .01$ yields $k = 10$. Proportion of tails is $X=.54n$ and substitution gives $$P(|.04n| \ge {5\sqrt n } ) \le .01$$

Squaring the inequality provides $$\frac{{16}}{{{{10}^4}}}{n^2} \ge 25n$$ so we need to solve $$(16n - 250000)n \ge 0$$ which gives $$n \ge 15625$$